# Get client id of the control

Tags: asp.net, .net, string

I got the client Id of dropdown value as

```
 ctl00_TimecardContentPlaceHolder_UC_0_1_drpdwnCompany
```

I have get the value from above string value as `1` only from that client Id.

Any methods like `substring()` are there to get that value specifically from that string.

### Solution

```
  GetClientIdFromConrol(Control control) 
  { 
       string strId=control.ClientID; 
       string strClientsId = strId.Substring(38, 1); 
       return Convert.ToInt32(strClientsId); 
  }
```

Comment: What is that you want to get ? Is it `ctl00_TimecardContentPlaceHolder_UC_0_1_drpdwnCompany`only `1` from that string?

Comment: why do you want `1` what is the purpose? Because it is of the `first-user-control` `dropdown list`?

Comment: I got the solution thanks for you kind answers                 private int GetClientIdFromConrol(Control control)
    {
        string strId=control.ClientID;
        string strClientsId = strId.Substring(38, 1);
        return Convert.ToInt32(strClientsId);
    } I used the Substring().

Comment: make sure you do some exception handling with that solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only 1.

you can use `split` function to do that job.

```
string dropdown="ctl00_TimecardContentPlaceHolder_UC_0_1_drpdwnCompany";
string[] split=dropdown.split('_');//split by underscore character;

string result=split[4].ToString(); // Here you will get 1 to the result
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sure this answer will helped me a lot. Because using substring(38,1) it will give as "1" thats not a problem. If  "ctl00_TimecardContentPlaceHolder_UC_0_10_drpdwnCompany" means there will be problem while we use substring(38,1) means answer will in one digit as "1". So this answer will help string dropdown="ctl00_TimecardContentPlaceHolder_UC_0_1_drpdwnCompany";
string[] split=dropdown.split('_');//split by underscore character;

string result=split[4].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Use `ID` not `ClientID`.

Also see[Control.ClientIDMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)